# Passing HTML entities through URL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass the Euro symbol i.e "€" and the "@" symbol, but they are not working, the euro symbol is looking like "â‚¬" and the "@" symbol is looking like "%40", I am using "**urlencode()**" function in PHP, but it doesn't seem to work, please let me know what could be wrong.

P.S I am transferring data from GET to another page then sending it in email, in email it is looking like the above.

EDIT: This is page 1:

```
    $temps=urlencode($temps);
    header('Location:http://someurl.com/mailx.php?data='.$temps);
```

This is page 2: Here I am emailing the data.

```
    $mailmsg = $_GET['data'];
```

Output seen in my email inbox:
Email: **name%40gmail.com**

Notice that %40 instead of "@"?

Comment: You'll need to show some code. Where exactly does the problem occur, where does the data come from?

Comment: Please see the editing I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `urldecode()`, read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

```
$var = "name%40gmail.com";
echo urldecode($var);
//output name@gmail.com
```